# JavaScript conditional font color change of part of text

Tags: javascript, string, vue.js, if-statement, vuejs2

I tried to change the font color of my String in my vue application based on a condition. However, the solutions I found so far changed the color for the whole text. I only want specific parts to be changed. For example:

```
const exampleString = 'Yesterday I was ACTIVITY with FRIEND who I first met in PLACE'
```

The words in capital letters should be in color red but the rest in black. So a condition like "if three subsequent chars are capital letters than color red until empty space". Is there a way to implement this ?

Comment: why not generate html with specified classes attached to the the text?

Comment: Because the Text is within a texarea and is dynamically generated with the option to replace the capital letter parts with predefined inputs. The setting is unfortunately given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it. You can simply loop over your content and add a condition that all the letters in a word should have the appropriate `ascii` value for capital letters, and if it passes this check, you can specify the color in a `span` tag. Here's a pure JavaScript example:

```js
var para = document.getElementById("para").innerHTML;
var resultPara = "";
var words = para.split(" ");

for (var word of words) {
  var capitalLetterCount = 0;
  for (var letter of word) {
    if (letter.charCodeAt(0) >= 65 && letter.charCodeAt(0) <= 90)
      capitalLetterCount++;
    else
      break;
  }
  if (capitalLetterCount != 0 && capitalLetterCount === word.length)
    resultPara += ' <span style="color: red">' + word + '</span>';
  else
    resultPara += ' ' + word;
}
document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = resultPara;
```

```html
<div id="para">Yesterday I was ACTIVITY with FRIEND who I first met in PLACE</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you ask how to do that with Vue, you can try with `v-html`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  data() {
    return {
      text: "Yesterday I was ACTIVITY with FRIEND who I first met in PLACE"
    }
  },
  computed: {
    setText() {
      return this.text.replace(/[A-Z&]/g, m => `<span style="color: red;">${m}</span>`)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-html="setText"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't use Vue but you may simply insert necessary `<span>`s with inline styling like;

```js
var str = 'Yesterday I was ACTIVITY with FRIEND who I first met in PLACE',
    rgx = new RegExp("[A-Z]{2,}","g"),
    res = str.replace(rgx, s => `<span style="color:red;">${s}</span>`);

console.log(res);
```