# Vue Textarea partially styling

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fonts, textarea, bootstrap-vue

In my application I have a bootstrap-vue textarea with a dynamic text as v-model. I want to change the font-color and font-weight of the displayed text within the textarea partially. I already know how it works outside of the textarea, but within I can't quite grasp how to achieve this. For example:

```
<b-textarea class="textarea" v-model="textareaText"></b-textarea>


data() {
   return {
      textareaText: 'Enter your NAME and your ADDRESS here.',
   };
},
```

And there should be a method or another approach to change the displayed words that are completely written in capital to red and bold and leave the rest of the text at normal. Is this possible within the displayed text in the textarea ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript conditional font color change of part of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70317157/javascript-conditional-font-color-change-of-part-of-text)

Comment: @NikolaPavicevic I guess he only asked that too

Comment: That is also my question and it solved the displayed text on the webpage in general, but this approach doesn't work within the textarea. The '`<span style="color: red;">${m}</span>`' is displayed as string in the textarea.

Comment: @random_programmer  hey mate, as far as I know you cannot put style in plain textarea element. In vue you can use v-html to display styled text or you can use some WYSIWYG editor, cheers :)